# How to simplify mysqli query for chart data?

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am trying to find a way to minimize this code.  In the top I get the current year.

```
//Get the current year
$theYear = date("Y", strtotime($day));
    if(isset($_POST['theYear'])){
        $theYear = $_POST['year_select'];
}
```

Further down I am getting the sum of hours for each week of the year.  My code has all 53 weeks but I have just grabbed 10 for reference.  It is set up as below.

```
$week01 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours01 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."01'");
$week02 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours02 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."02'");
$week03 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours03 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."03'");
$week04 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours04 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."04'");
$week05 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours05 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."05'");
$week06 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours06 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."06'");
$week07 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours07 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."07'");
$week08 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours08 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."08'");
$week09 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours09 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."09'");
$week10 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours10 FROM timecard WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) = '".$theYear."10'");
```

I tried doing a while loop but found it was too many layers of php to properly work.  So I echoed a while loop to give me the queries below and then copy pasted into my code.

Below the above code I grab all the data as well and used the same method as above to repeat the code output.

```
$Total01 = mysqli_fetch_object($week01);
$Total02 = mysqli_fetch_object($week02);
$Total03 = mysqli_fetch_object($week03);
$Total04 = mysqli_fetch_object($week04);
$Total05 = mysqli_fetch_object($week05);
$Total06 = mysqli_fetch_object($week06);
$Total07 = mysqli_fetch_object($week07);
$Total08 = mysqli_fetch_object($week08);
$Total09 = mysqli_fetch_object($week09);
$Total10 = mysqli_fetch_object($week10);
```

So then all this data gets echoed into cells in a table and then converted into a graph but only if there were hours for the week.  So the graph grows as we log hours for future weeks instead of having a large blank space to the right at the beginning of the year and slowly filling it in.

```
<? if(($Total01->tHours01) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total01->tHours01)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total01->tHours01;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total02->tHours02) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total02->tHours02)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total02->tHours02;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total03->tHours03) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total03->tHours03)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total03->tHours03;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total04->tHours04) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total04->tHours04)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total04->tHours04;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total05->tHours05) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total05->tHours05)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total05->tHours05;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total06->tHours06) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total06->tHours06)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total06->tHours06;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total07->tHours07) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total07->tHours07)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total07->tHours07;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total08->tHours08) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total08->tHours08)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total08->tHours08;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total09->tHours09) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total09->tHours09)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total09->tHours09;}?></td><? } ?>
<? if(($Total10->tHours10) > 0) { ?><td><? if(empty($Total10->tHours10)){echo '0';}else{ echo $Total10->tHours10;}?></td><? } ?>
```

All this works fine and dandy but I am curious if there is a way to do it that I am unaware of?

Comment: "too many layers of php to properly work" - what does that mean? It sounds like you just didn't write the while loop correctly. Maybe your question should be "what's wrong with this while loop?".

This seems like it's probably a homework question, so I'm not going to give too much detail, but I'd suggest having a look at how the SQL `group by` command works.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Ok so when I said that what I was referring to was I had a while loop setup and it would do everything I wanted it to do such as printing out all the code but the page would not run the code after it had already run the while loop.  I am sure this does not make much more sense but I am having trouble describing what I mean.

edit: Trying to hit return and it just submits the comment.  

Also this is a project I am doing on the side to try and escape the manual labor field and get into programming.  So not exactly homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce the amount of requests to the database you can create more complicated query, that will fetch all the data needed and then render it properly.

Considering the chart data must be continuous, all possible week values are needed to be present.
In order to generate the sequence of continuous numbers multiple approaches can be picked. Some of them need new table generation, while others can produce the sequence without direct table manipulation. [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75839) helps with this task.

So, **let's pick the range of week numbers to show**. It could be easily from 1 to 53 or something else. For the query example, let them be **from 20 to 35** and basic value for these weeks will be 0 hours worked.

```
# SEQUENCE OF WEEK NUMBERS NEEDED
SELECT (SELECT 0) AS tHours, (t*10+u+1) AS tWeek FROM
(SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
(SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
HAVING tWeek BETWEEN 20 AND 35;
```

Also we need to get a data about the actual **amount of working hours per week**.
That could be done easily with the help of the following query:

```
# WEEKLY HOURS;
SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours, WEEK(date, 1) AS tWeek
FROM timecard
WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) BETWEEN 200920 AND 200935
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date, 1);
```

So to get all the data needed we can combine previous queries, and they will look like in the following example:

```
# RESULT QUERY
SELECT SUM(tHours) AS tHours, tWeek 
FROM 
    ((SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours, WEEK(date, 1) AS tWeek
        FROM timecard
        WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) BETWEEN 200920 AND 200935
        GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date, 1))
    UNION
    (SELECT (SELECT 0) AS tHours, (t*10+u+1) AS tWeek FROM
        (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
        SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
        (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
        SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
        HAVING tWeek BETWEEN 20 AND 35
    ORDER BY tWeek)) data
GROUP BY tWeek;
```

These examples with resulting output are provided [here](http://rextester.com/SLIZXZ16789).

The next step will be to execute this query from your script and render the results.
I have not worked with PHP for a while, so sorry if the code will be messy. I will try to write example code simply to show you the way how to operate with the results.

Let's assume you already have `$theYear` variable.
The next step is to choose the range of week numbers to show.

```
$startWeek = 20;
$endWeek = 35;
```

Query object will be like this:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(tHours) AS tHours, tWeek ".
"FROM ". 
    "((SELECT SUM(hours) AS tHours, WEEK(date, 1) AS tWeek ".
        "FROM timecard ".
        "WHERE YEARWEEK(date, 1) BETWEEN ".
        $theYear.$startWeek." AND ".
        $theYear.$endWeek." ".
        "GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date, 1)) ".
    "UNION ".
    "(SELECT (SELECT 0) AS tHours, (t*10+u+1) AS tWeek FROM ".
        "(SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION ".
        "SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A, ".
        "(SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION ".
        "SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B ".
        "HAVING tWeek BETWEEN ".$startWeek." AND ".$endWeek." ".
    "ORDER BY tWeek)) data ".
"GROUP BY tWeek";
```

Next logical step is to get the data from the database:

```
$weeks = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

And we need to render the results at last, which can be done multiple ways, for example:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($weeks, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $result = "<td>".$row['tHours']."</td>"; // $row['tWeek'] also can be rendered
    echo $result;
}
```

So, this approach gives opportunity to reduce the number of database requests greatly and increase overall performance, and to decrease the response time of your application. Also the range of the weeks may vary simply by changing the corresponding variables.
The code is less polluted with unneeded variables, though SQL request became more complicated.

This code could be written differently in multiple ways, and possibly there is a place for further improvements. So I simply shared my point of view and yours can differ.

Thank you for reading.